# Load Testing with JMeter - will it log into my site at load?

Tags: session, jmeter, load-testing

I wish to use JMeter to login to my site, run some reports and log out again as a load test.

Is JMeter the best tool for this? I'm concerned it doesn't maintain the browser session between requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use jmeter for this. It supports maintaining session across requests and the scenario you want to test is pretty common one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very easily in JMeter. You need to create a HTTP Request Sampler (action type needs to be post), then add all the form fields as parameters (username, password etc) and have the path set to the form target. You'll also need to ensure that you have a HTTP cookie manager set to stay logged in. It's even possible to log in as different users, I wrote a blog on it here for full details on how to [load test with multiple user logins in JMeter](http://javadevsoup.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/jmeter-load-testing-java-web.html).